# Different URLS navigated inside a Web View in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using a web view inside a Xamarin.forms application.

The Url of the webview is a site written in javascript. Is there a way we can handle/know the different URLs that we visit inside that webview?

I have tried the navigating method on the webview.

The event gets fired the first time I am trying to navigate to a page inside the website. 
Page1 ---> Page2

When I try to navigate back to Page 1 from Page 2, The navigating event does not get fired.
I am trying to set a flag to display or hide the header. What is a better way to do this?

Page 1 and Page 2 are the pages inside my site ===> "https://www.mywebsite.com";

```
webview.Url = "https://www.mywebsite.com";

webview.navigating += (object sender, EventArgs e) {
if(e.Url.Contains("/page1")) {
   //show the header
 } else{
   // Hide the header
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` provides two methods `GoForward()` and `GoBack()` to navigate forward and last.

**GoForward()** – if CanGoForward is true, calling GoForward navigates forward to the next visited page.

**GoBack()** – if CanGoBack is true, calling GoBack will navigate to the last visited page.

You coulc check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#Navigation

And you could download the source file from the link for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithwebview/